# How to limit results in a SharePoint XSL query

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, xpath

I am creating a SharePoint site that we will use to report issues with trucks used in our business. Linked to the list I have created will be a page that will display an overview of the trucks and a little truck icon will show the trucks current status. Green and the truck is okay (no open issues), Red and the truck have an open issue with status "Undrivable", Orange and there is two issues open that requires the user to look further into the truck before using it and finally a Gray truck for when there is a new issue created that has not been looked into (not sure if it is drivable or not).

I have managed to create the "Dashboard" and with my limit XSL/XPATH knowledge been able to add a truck and replicate the description above but... in my test I have created 4 issues, for example if three of them are changed to status Closed and one left to Undrivable I will get four icons on the page, three with Green trucks and the last one Red. So in theory it works but I obviously only want to see the last truck, one truck. I am not interested in seeing the others.

```
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.rowview">
 <xsl:variable name="CountReport" select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Highloader='GGEU12' and @Status!='Closed'])" />
 <xsl:variable name="MoreThan" select="$CountReport &gt; 1" />
 <xsl:variable name="NoReports" select="$CountReport = 0" />
 <xsl:variable name="Closed" select=" @Highloader='GGEU12' and @Status='Closed'" />
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$MoreThan">
<div class="ms-vb"><img title='More than one report exist!' border='0' alt='In Progress' src='highloader/Library/hl-orange.png' /></div>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
   <div class="ms-vb"><xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="@Icon" /></div>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

My hope is that someone with slightly more knowledge can find the last piece of the puzzle for me! 
Thanks for reading and asking questions to fill any gap I left above.

David

Comment: Hi David i'm not able to understand what help you want from us it would be better if you can precise your requirement to one or two lines

Comment: Hello Ashutosh, my requirment is the dashboard detailed above so either another solution to that or an answer to how to limit the output to only one truck with the existing method.
If I do a paging limit on the dataview webpart I get only one truck icon but it is not the correct one (i.e in the example of multiple issues that display an orange truck it will display four orange trucks without paging but with paging it will display the very first issues status icon that may be a green one.)

Comment: I'm still not able to understand clearly do you want one row for each category and count of how many tucks are in each category

Comment: The idea is to have a kpi dashboard showing the trucks in the business. One image per truck, either green, orange, red or gray depending on the result of the status column returned from the list. Problem is there will be more than one item per truck.
For ex. if there is an item that says the truck got a broken heater but is drivable it should be green, if another issue comes in saying there is a flat tire the first issue still exist but obviously the truck is no longer drivable. At the moment this returns 2 orange truck icons. I want to limit this to showing one.

Comment: @David: Your question is not clear. First, there is no input sample. Second, your are matching `dvt_1.rowview` elements but then you use an absolute expression in `CountReport` variable, two exclusive boolean expressions, and a **relative** boolean expression...

Comment: @David: If you really need help, please, provide a complete (but as small as possible) XML document, a complete (but as small as possible) XSLT transformation, the result you get and the result you want to get, and explain what is the problem with the result that is currently produced. Refrain from using problem domain terms as "truck", because we are obviously not experts in your problem domain.

Comment: Guys, I added an answer to rephrase my question and added a simplified setup as requested.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your comments. Please find below a simplified version of the "Dashboard" that works exactly like I want it to. You can change the last status:undrivable to "closed" to see the page display only the first issue with status Drivable.

issues.xml:

```
<catalog>
<issue>
    <title>Crack on the window</title>
    <truck>GGEU12</truck>
    <status>Drivable</status>
</issue>
<issue>
    <title>Need new smelling tree</title>
    <truck>GGEU12</truck>
    <status>Closed</status>
</issue>
<issue>
    <title>Topping up cooling</title>
    <truck>GGEU12</truck>
    <status>Closed</status>
</issue>
<issue>
    <title>Flat tire</title>
    <truck>GGEU12</truck>
    <status>Undrivable</status>
</issue>
</catalog>
```

status.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="CountIssues" select="count(catalog/issue[(truck)='GGEU12' and (status)!='Closed'])" />
<xsl:variable name="MoreThan" select="$CountIssues &gt; 1" />

<html>
<body>
<h2>Truck Status Dashboard</h2>
<table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Truck</th>
  </tr>

<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$MoreThan">

  <tr>
    <td>Orange truck icon</td>
    <td>Orange truck icon</td>
  </tr>

</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>

  <xsl:for-each select="catalog/issue[(truck)='GGEU12' and (status)!='Closed']">

  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="truck"/></td>
  </tr>

  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

</table>

</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So the problem I am having is with SharePoint. I have tried to include everything that I have on the page but I suspect you guys have to reproduce my setup to see the issue. Below example will produce a list of the four issues as above and a value-of select that shows the amount the count variable get which is 2 and that is displayed four times (as many items as exists):

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="loc:Row1" ID="Row1" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Orientation="Horizontal"><ZoneTemplate>
<WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart runat="server" IsIncluded="True" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" ViewFlag="0" Title="Service Requests" __markuptype="vsattributemarkup" partorder="1" __WebPartId="{F711505C-6DEC-414D-9742-9327B43A6EB4}" id="g_f711505c_6dec_414d_9742_9327b43a6eb4">
<DataSources><SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List" UseInternalName="true" selectcommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;/View&gt;" id="dataformwebpart2"><SelectParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{EDBDB620-5543-464F-801A-891B15105E59}"/></SelectParameters><DeleteParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{EDBDB620-5543-464F-801A-891B15105E59}"/></DeleteParameters><UpdateParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{EDBDB620-5543-464F-801A-891B15105E59}"/></UpdateParameters><InsertParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{EDBDB620-5543-464F-801A-891B15105E59}"/></InsertParameters></SharePoint:SPDataSource></DataSources>

<datafields>@Title,Titel;@Status,Status;@truck,truck;</datafields>
<XSL><xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
<xsl:decimal-format NaN=""/>
<xsl:param name="dvt_apos">'</xsl:param>
<xsl:variable name="dvt_1_automode">0</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:call-template name="dvt_1"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="dvt_1">
<xsl:variable name="dvt_StyleName">Table</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row"/>
    <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
        <tr valign="top">
            <xsl:if test="$dvt_1_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
                <th class="ms-vh" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap"></th>
            </xsl:if>
            <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="nowrap">Truck</th>
            <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="nowrap">Status</th>
        </tr>
                    <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.body">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.body">
<xsl:param name="Rows"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
<xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.rowview"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.rowview">
 <xsl:variable name="CountIssues" select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@truck='GGEU12' and @Status!='closed'])" />
 <xsl:value-of select="$CountIssues" />
    <tr>
                    <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="class">ms-alternating</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="$dvt_1_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
            <td class="ms-vb" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap">
                <span ddwrt:amkeyfield="ID" ddwrt:amkeyvalue="ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID))" ddwrt:ammode="view"></span>
            </td>
        </xsl:if>
        <td class="ms-vb">
            <xsl:value-of select="@truck"/>
        </td>
        <td class="ms-vb">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Status"/>
    g   </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The wouldbe assistant to the solution should create a new list, with three column, truck, title and status. Create a new webpart page and in SharePoint designer create a dataview of the list and the xsl goal here is to display an green icon if the status of the truck is drivable (or no reports exist), red when undrivable and finally an orange icon if there is more than two issues with conflicting statuses. When I do this it displays as many icons as there are issues.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I think I have figured it out... The problem was caused by SharePoint adding quite a few other templates to display the data. I removed most of it leaving just one and I got it working as my simplified example. Thank you all for leading me onto the obvious path of simplifying!